# TypeScript incorrectly inferring generic parameter

Tags: typescript

I have a TypeScript function with a generic parameter:

```
function processNodes<N>(nodes: Nodes<N>)
```

There are 2 types - 'Nodes' and 'NodesImpl'. `NodesImpl<N>` effectively extends `Nodes<N>`.

I am calling the 'processNodes' function like so:

```
const nodes: NodesImpl<string> = null as any
const r = processNodes(event.currentTarget, nodes)
```

This fails with the error: `TS2345: Argument of type 'NodesImpl<string>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Nodes<string | undefined>'.` Somehow, typescript infers the generic parameter `N` of 'processNodes' to be `string | undefined` instead of just string, which causes the entire line to fail. A workaround is to manually specify the type: `processNodes<string>(nodes)`.

However, the type inference fails in a very peculiar way, requiring a very complex setup to achieve the error, which is why I can't seem to possibly figure it out. This is a minimal reproducible example:

```
export interface FunctionComponent<P> { (props: P): null }
// Changing any of the 2 types to non-array (removing any '[]'): no more error
interface NodesFunctions<T> { doSomething(node: Node<T>[] | NodeData<T>[]): void }

interface Node<T> {
    data: T // if type is string - no more error
    Component: FunctionComponent<T> // if type is literally anything else - no more error
}
type NodeData<T> = Partial<Node<T>>
// How does this cause the error?
type Nodes<N>  = Node<N>[] & NodesFunctions<N>
type Nodes2<N> = Node<N>[] & NodesFunctions<N>

function processNodes<N>(nodes: Nodes<N>) {}

function f() {
    // Replacing with 'Nodes<string>' works
    const nodes: Nodes2<string> = null as any
    // Error on this line:
    processNodes(nodes)
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgMQFclsYEIkBhCAW0iWBQB4AFAPjgG84AKMKCGADOALjgsAlGKSEANrLgBfAFAB6VXEoALTEgDmyPXF0BPOBHRwYWvACYrJsMCFWIcJBQC0mKFExmeKGAaCAA3Q2MkMwByAG0AXWipdzcQoLg0AShlZFQMHDwAOQgAE2ciEjIKISYAFQ5uEogAZVpga0MeDzKxYrK6tgS4AB84PuAAEUwYTAGE5NCIBBKlZRyUNCxcMdLgAa5lOCO4EunMMVq4dURLGEc8BBchGCgIzxS4NLxM6EPj6joFEYMDEFVI5CotHowP21wQt3uiBcsgQeUw8jMpg6+gysiEeHeHk+0G+vl+KjuTh2ZSmM32AF5xD4yOimOMBmw1BoABIQADuJwgzisWkecGwmEI+JFpKyAH5lJSirsaoUOHBGey1UMAGTU8rEcHVNmcpX6oS2E0a-Um3XmsFVJCqznKdCGx1wfgQXBCITjZ1dFW9FUmiRcFSu90QuDoHhhzh-I7YarwbrOYNlC1MZ6vfQcRkyeTGFymRNXDQAUTJUHMSBFYpRDBEZa9Pr9KsDmYkykUQA)

'Nodes' and 'Nodes2' are identical, so, as TypeScript is a structurally-typed language, it *shouldn't* matter which one you use, yet here it does.

It's also interesting to note that by changing almost any line of the entire file, the error goes away, as suggested by the comments in the example.

Why is the type inference failing in the provided example when using 'Nodes2' instead of 'Nodes', and why? This looks like an issue with the TypeScript compiler itself.

Comment: `type Nodes<N> = Node<N>[] & NodesFunctions<N>` (and the same thing for `NodesImpl`) is a fairly unusual construct. It says that to be a `Nodes<N>`, something has to both be an array of nodes **and** have a `doSomething` method. While it's possible to do that (since you can create array instances with extra functions, or even subclass arrays), it's highly unusual. Is that intentional? Or did you mean `|` for "an array of nodes **or** an object with a `doSomething` method"? Or even `Array<Node<N> | NodeFunctions<N>>` (an array that contains `Node<N>` instances and/or `NodeFunctions<N>` insts)?

Comment: Making it `|` instead of `&` makes the error go away (https://tsplay.dev/WG2OMm), but that's meaningless if it's not what you're trying to do. :-)

Comment: I'm not sure how to make much headway in answering this question since the types are complicated enough that chasing down the inference candidates and priorities is tedious.  And at the end of it, the particular failure mode will probably be less illuminating that you'd want. ...

Comment: ... Pragmatically, inference needs to be helped along by making the type of the value you're inferring from a very simple and direct function of the type you're trying to infer.  You could try to block inference from part of that structure like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WYLpdm) as discussed in [ms/TS#14829](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829). Does any of this constitute an answer for you, or are you really looking for a detailed analysis of where the inference breaks down?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes that is correct, it's an array with extra functions attached to it

Comment: @jcalz To be fair, only after I finished editing the question I realised how complex this issue is, that may or may not even be an incredibly obscure bug in the TypeScript type inference system itself. However it is very curious to me that it infers 'undefined' as part of the type when the word itself appears nowhere in the source code. My guess is that it could be something with the `(props: P): P` line (which I don't understand) and the optional (possibly undefined) properties it creates?

Comment: It's the `Partial`.  If you have `Partial<{data: T}>` and infer `T` from it, you might get `undefined` in there (e.g., `Partial<{data: string}>["data"]` is `string | undefined`).  So, uh, how do you want to proceed here?  Should I write up an answer going over this stuff?

Comment: @jcalz Just updated the question with an even better example, getting closer to the root of the problem.

Comment: A full structural comparison between two types can be slow, so the compiler takes shortcuts when it can.  If you are trying to do inference like `F<T> extends F<infer U> ? U : never` then the compiler will take the shortcut of inferring `T` without even consulting the definition of `F`, or needing to do a structural comparison.  But if you are inferring `F<T> extends G<infer U> ? U : never` then the compiler will have to start consulting `F` and `G`, and depending on heuristics, it might have to compare them structurally. And so inference details can change.

Comment: For example, there's a related github issue at [ms/TS#48116](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48116).  Let me know how you'd like to proceed.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for the link. I think you could create an answer summarizing what causes the issue, and I'll keep watch of the issue.

Comment: Okay I'll write up an answer when I get a chance; it's getting close to my bedtime so I'll probably do so tomorrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TypeScript's type inference is effectively a set of heuristic rules that perform well over a wide range of situations, but do not claim to be perfect or ideal, and it will sometimes behave in ways that are apparently inconsistent or unsuitable for certain use cases.

There are some type systems that have a well-defined inference algorithm that always works (for some definitions of "always" and "works").  For example, the [Hindley-Milner type system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner_type_system) is the basis for [the Haskell programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell)'s types, and Haskell has a robust and "correct" type inference algorithm.  TypeScript doesn't use this system, though.  There is a discussion at [microsoft/TypeScript#30134](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30134) about possibly implementing a full [unification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science)) algorithm for inference.  It's unlikely to happen since it would be a massive change in the compiler, and according to [a comment in microsoft/TypeScript#17520](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17520#issuecomment-318935065) from the TS team's lead architect, the current algorithm

> differs from the unification based type inference implemented by some functional programming languages, but it has the distinct advantage of being able to make partial inferences in incomplete code which is hugely beneficial to statement completion in IDEs.

So for better or worse, TypeScript's type inference isn't ideal, and it isn't always going to be illuminating to dig into a particular edge case to see why something undesirable happens, because you're likely to find an interaction of some set of heuristic rules that make sense most of the time.

---

In particular, the question of why you can get different type inference results when replacing one type with a structurally identical type can be answered by pointing out that structural comparisons an be *very slow* and the compiler will try to avoid doing that if possible.  For example, see [this comment in the unmerged PR microsoft/TypeScript#48080](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/48080#issuecomment-1066199064).

If you have the type `F<T>` and you are trying to match it against `F<infer U>`, the compiler can take the shortcut of inferring `U` as `T` without even needing to evaluate or consult the definition of `F`.  That means the compiler tends to treat `F` as [nominally typed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system) for the check, resulting in the weird situation where even unused type parameters can be inferred:

```
interface Foo<T> { } // don't do this

type X = Foo<string> extends Foo<infer T> ? T : never;
// type X = string
type Y = Foo<number> extends Foo<infer T> ? T : never;
// type Y = number
```

If TS always fell back to a full structural comparison, that would never happen.  And since it sometimes does do structural comparisons, it's a bad idea to have an unused type parameter, [as described in this FAQ entry](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-type-inference-work-on-this-interface-interface-foot--).

On the other hand, if you have the type `F<T>` and are trying to match it against `G<infer U>`, the compiler will need to start consulting the definition of `F` and `G` to proceed.  Even if it turns out that `F` and `G` are structurally identical, the compiler might never be able to take the shortcut of just using `F` in place of `G`:

```
interface Bar<T> { }

type Z = Foo<string> extends Bar<infer T> ? T : never;
// type Z = unknown // not string
```

In your code, the following call can take the shortcut of ignoring `Nodes`'s definition and just matching on `N`, because the type of `nodes1` and the type of the `nodes` parameter of `processNodes()` are both written in terms of `Nodes`:

```
declare function processNodes<N>(nodes: Nodes<N>): void;
declare const nodes1: Nodes<string>;
processNodes(nodes); // infers string
```

but if you change the type of `nodes1` to be `Nodes2<string>`, the compiler has no choice but to start examining the definitions of `Nodes` and `Nodes2`, and even though they are structurally identical, the compiler misses its opportunity to take the shortcut, and you get different inference behavior:

```
declare const nodes2: Nodes2<string>;
processNodes(nodes2); // does not infer string
```

There are occasionally issues in GitHub where this crops up, such as [microsoft/TypeScript#48116](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48116), but it's not an easy problem to solve.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0B4AqA+ZAb2QF8AoMsATwAcUANZAXjUywGcwpQBzAiAB6QQAE3atsoGNGT5kAflnIAXMhAQAbtADcZAPR7k1OskYtO3ED0q0UATWYSsIAK4BbAEbR+QiKPEYkiDSULIEijgqapo6+obG9o6untAUZKCQsIgoAEJwULgExOQ2JgBajoEcXLw+wmLIeQVSMnIRUepaULoGRrbIFSwuIADWIOgA7iBpgjToUGDIGdDwSGjDCGDA6CAAwuhuc+rgWAAKRcgAFDRQ6DTsqqcAlKquADZvpHHIuwAWcFZeMgAVRkOgYEZfigAEx9OjiMDoNQ7AC0+SgcFBlygEDc6A0QJByAA5ABtAC6xJeyOQeJxyGgtyg6XAK2yyAAcugRBB2KgNlsduxCkRkCJ0ABlA4QMC-XiXcY81RcnmFCnIAA+nO5EAAInAwHA1eTqRp0MARF8WZlVigVRARYQyMgXWKDXBVJFesAIQkluILECUTS6ShGfNna79ocdn4wKp+SBNts9gcjnGRd7ff1gOI3sBMnAPqCQbKgRA3uwUMHxrT5mGoEyyOQ-fb9YaRSxTvktkWsPbCnhvgAJSZi9C8yG55AIOAuKuQhtM+SlO064UcgiOAeb9UAMm1PL5ApTG6HrfX0P7BBYO7w+8PvMTyaF14oMBPO2QN3QSHY7HtM8FXXZV12vJ4iBKD8k0FEBkBgS4IKdV0ZyFRZFV5ABGUCj2qSw+CSFwPmBcQQUjF0fz-AD12Ao9MKebRkAoFCEDQ5Ej2hHDeSvQMrBvNQiM+OBSJAKhyO-W4qMA2juIYigSCAA)